# Capturing image through camera, even being inside application

Tags: iphone, ios4, camera

Is it possible to make camera work from, application code? As here is need to capture Image inside my application through iPhone camera. And to upload that on web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yes.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html)